# Neither xrandr can't detect second monitor at highes resolution nor permit adding

Tags: manjaro, cinnamon, multi-monitor, xrandr

In case an additional monitor would be great 
But problem so big
Manjaro Cinnamon doesn't recognize **HP 14455/LE1901w** LCD Monitor's higher resolutions.

Also xrandr command doesn't support "1440 x 900 @ 60 Hz;1280 x 1024 @ 60 Hz and 75 Hz; 1280 x 960 @ 60 Hz" resolutions which support in specification document document [details](https://www.manualslib.com/manual/418142/Hp-Nk570aa.html?page=2#manual) says

```
Resolutions supported: 1440 x 900 @ 60 Hz;1280 x 1024 @ 60 Hz and 75 Hz; 1280 x 960 @ 60 Hz;  
                       1024 x 768 @ 60 Hz and 75 Hz; 800 x 600 @ 60 Hz and 75 Hz; 
                       640 x 480 @ 60 Hz and 75 Hz; 1152 x 720 @ 60 Hz;1280 x 768 @ 60 Hz;  
                       720 x 400 @ 70 Hz; 1152 x 870 @ 75 Hz and 832 x 624 @ 75 Hz
```

Additionally doesn't accept adding a new one!

```
  xrandr --newmode "1440x900_60.00"  60.00 1440 900 1024 1064 1168 1312  600 601 604 622  -HSync +Vsync
  xrandr: unrecognized option '622'
  Try 'xrandr --help' for more information.

Xrandr detect some resolutions by default

    xrandr --verbose

    VGA1 connected 1024x768+0+0 (0x15c) normal (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 0mm x 0mm
    Identifier: 0x48
    Timestamp:  64675771
    Subpixel:   unknown
    Gamma:      1.0:1.0:1.0
    Brightness: 1.0
    Clones:    
    CRTC:       1
    CRTCs:      0 1 2
    Transform:  1.000000 0.000000 0.000000
                0.000000 1.000000 0.000000
                0.000000 0.000000 1.000000
               filter: 
    link-status: Good 
        supported: Good, Bad
    non-desktop: 0 
        range: (0, 1)
  1024x768 (0x15c) 65.000MHz -HSync -VSync *current
        h: width  1024 start 1048 end 1184 total 1344 skew    0 clock  48.36KHz
        v: height  768 start  771 end  777 total  806           clock  60.00Hz
  800x600 (0x163) 40.000MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width   800 start  840 end  968 total 1056 skew    0 clock  37.88KHz
        v: height  600 start  601 end  605 total  628           clock  60.32Hz
  800x600 (0x164) 36.000MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width   800 start  824 end  896 total 1024 skew    0 clock  35.16KHz
        v: height  600 start  601 end  603 total  625           clock  56.25Hz
  848x480 (0x27b) 33.750MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width   848 start  864 end  976 total 1088 skew    0 clock  31.02KHz
        v: height  480 start  486 end  494 total  517           clock  60.00Hz
  640x480 (0x168) 25.175MHz -HSync -VSync
        h: width   640 start  656 end  752 total  800 skew    0 clock  31.47KHz
        v: height  480 start  490 end  492 total  525           clock  59.94Hz
VIRTUAL1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
    Identifier: 0x49
    Timestamp:  64675771
    Subpixel:   no subpixels
    Clones:    
    CRTCs:      3
    Transform:  1.000000 0.000000 0.000000
                0.000000 1.000000 0.000000
                0.000000 0.000000 1.000000
               filter: 
    non-desktop: 0 
        supported: 0, 1
```

I want to add this external monitor as second screen, but many people uses `--same as` and `-miror` command. What is reverse of them because I need additional one.

Does any way for auto detect on Manjaro Cinnamon?

How can I restore setting of xrandr?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think xrandr shows resolutions, which can be displayed on that monitor via the graphics adapter and cable. Maybe the combination of graphics adapter, cable and monitor do not support higher resolutions. I had a similar problem once, when I was trying many options until I found out that HDMI 2 DVI converter connected between computer and monitor suported only single link DVI with highest resolution 1920x1080.

It also seems that modeline which you provide to xrandr is not correct as it is complaining about 622.

Try the program `cvt`:

```
cvt 1440 900 60
```

It displays the following modeline for me:

```
# 1440x900 59.89 Hz (CVT 1.30MA) hsync: 55.93 kHz; pclk: 106.50 MHz
Modeline "1440x900_60.00"  106.50  1440 1528 1672 1904  900 903 909 934 -hsync +vsync
```

You can try that one with xrandr, but I think, it will not work either.

The utilities `get-edid` and `parse-edid` can tell you about monitor resolutions a lot, too. You can run `get-edid` to download EDID information from the monitor and `parse-edid` to parse that information. Look [here](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/get-edid.1.html).

Comment: Thank It helped so much. cvt impressive

Answer (score 1):

Thanks [nobody](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/130631/nobody)

cvt helped so much

```
cvt 1440 900 60
# 1440x900 59.89 Hz (CVT 1.30MA) hsync: 55.93 kHz; pclk: 106.50 MHz
Modeline "1440x900_60.00"  106.50  1440 1528 1672 1904  900 903 909 934 -hsync +vsync
```

xrandr accepted this configuration

```
xrandr --newmode "1440x900_60.00"  106.50  1440 1528 1672 1904  900 903 909 934 -hsync +vsync
xrandr --addmode VGA1 1440x900_60.00  
xrandr --output VGA1 --mode 1440x900_60.00
```

I chanded miror section on display setting. It is greal as I expected

Additionally `get-edid` and `parse-edid` commands alternative in Arch is `edid-decode`  but response time long. I can't wait long enouh.

Comment: Great! I am glad you managed to make it work.

Comment: @nobody thanks it seemed a big problem. With your help, it got a small one